# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate: Invalid use of argument matchers. 3 matchers expected, 4 recorded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

Below is my test case,

```
@Test
    public void aTestOfMocks() throws SQLException
    {


        when(dbTemplate.query(anyString(), anyMap(), Matchers.<ResultSetExtractor<List<Order>>>any())).thenReturn(list);

        final List<Employee> actual = xxx.getEmployeeByDate("2020-05-29");
        assertNotNull(actual, "error message");
    }
```

Below is my actual code,

```
@Override
    public List<Order> getEmployeeByDate(String startDate)
    {
        final Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("startDate", startDate);

        final String limiterQuery = "query";

        final boolean includeTest = false;

        return queryForEmployee(limiterQuery, parameters, includeTest);
    }

        private List<Employee> queryForEmployee(
                    String limiterQuery,
                    Map<String, String> parameters,
                    boolean includeTest)
            {
    ResultSetExtractor<List<Order>> resultExtractor;
                final String query = limiterQuery + commonQueryForOrder(includeTestOrders);

                final List<Order> result = dbTemplate.query(query, parameters, resultExtractor);

                if (result == null)
                {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                else
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

When I run this test getting error as

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 4 recorded:
```

Is there anything i am missing here? I have searched anc verified similar posts in stackoverflow but nothing helped me out to solve this.

Comment: what version of junit are you using?

Comment: @MensurQulami Junit 5

Comment: Then can you try `ArgumentMatchers.any()` instead of the current one? Without those generic arguments. Also, shouldn't `resultExtractor` be initialized or is it just put there for brevity?